# Is there any program to edit multiple po files?

Tags: django, bash, localization, translation

I have django project and it has four languages:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ru', _('Russian')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('de', _('Deutsch')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    BASE_DIR + '/locales',
)
```

So, I have four different files "django.po" in folders ./locales/[lang_symbol]/LC_MESSAGES/django.po

msgid and msgstr often have multiple lines.

I want to create csv file to get all msgstr and assigned  them to msgid from "en" file, like this:

```
"msgid";"en";"ru";"fr";"de"
"contact";"";"Контакт","contact";"kontakt"
[etc]
```

I must create from this files one document with all translations, one per row. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [polib](http://polib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) to parse .po files. Here is script that should do the job or get you started for customising.

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

import polib

path_template = 'locales/{}/LC_MESSAGES/django.po'

# Hardcoded codes version.
langs = ['en', 'ru', 'fr', 'de',]

# You can use settings.LANGUAGES version for more versatility.
# Just remember that default i18n language (LANG_CODE) might not be the first on list of LANGUAGES in your project so msgid might be wrong in that case.
#langs = [lang[0] for lang in settings.LANGUAGES]

rows = OrderedDict()  
rows['header'] = ['msgid'] + langs

for lang_code in langs:
    po_path = path_template.format(lang_code)
    po = polib.pofile(po_path)

    for entry in po:
        msgid = entry.msgid.encode('utf-8')
        msgstr = entry.msgstr.encode('utf-8')

        if msgid in rows.keys():
            rows[msgid].append(msgstr)
        else:
            rows[msgid] = [msgid, msgstr]

with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(rows.values())
```

Run from root of project or change paths for files used to your needs.

There might be some tweaks needed for full 1:1 transition so mentioning from top of my head.

1. **Accessing and adding plural forms** (not included in above version). You can access them using `entry` attributes `msgstr_plural` and `msgid_plural`. CSV format you mentioned might be  limited in storing multiple plural form though. Don't know the CSV final purpose also.
2. **Accessing fuzzy or obsolete translations** - 
   check iteration examples on [polib documentation](http://polib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#iterating-over-entries) to access those if needed.